# Differential equation with derivatives elevated to the time power.

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I started with the apparently real differential equation $(X'')^t+(X')^t+X^t=0$, where $t$ is the time and $X$ depends on $t$, but realized it was necessarily complex, so I switched from $X$ to $z$:

$(z'')^t+(z')^t+z^t=0$

$e^{t \ln z''}+e^{t \ln z'} + e^{t \ln z}=0$

$e^{t (\ln z'' - \ln z)}+e^{t (\ln z' - \ln z)} + 1=0$

$e^{t (\ln z'' - \ln z)}+e^{t (\ln z' - \ln z)} = - 1$

Here I realized it was indeed complex, since at least one of the exponentials needs to be negative.

$e^{t(\ln(e^{|z''|+i arg(z'')})-\ln(e^{|z|+i arg(z)}))}+e^{t(\ln(e^{|z'|+i arg(z')})-\ln(e^{|z|+i arg(z)}))}=-1$

$e^{t((|z''|+i arg(z''))-(|z|+i arg(z)))}+e^{t((|z'|+i arg(z'))-(|z|+i arg(z)))}=-1$

Splitting into the real and imaginary parts:

$e^{t\left(|z''|-|z|\right)}cos(t(arg(z'')-arg(z))+e^{t\left(|z'|-|z|\right)}cos(t(arg(z')-arg(z)))=-1$

$e^{t\left(|z''|-|z|\right)}sin(t(arg(z'')-arg(z))) +e^{t\left(|z'|-|z|^2\right)}sin(t(arg(z')-arg(z)))=0$

Taking the first cosine as negative, since at least one of them has to be negative.

$cos(t(arg(z'')-arg(z)))<0$

$t(arg(z'')-arg(z))< arcos(0)$

Considering angles from $0$ to $2\pi$ for simplicity.

$\pi/2<t(arg(z'')-arg(z))< 3\pi/2$

$t^{-1}\pi/2<arg(z'')-arg(z)< t^{-1}3\pi/2; t>0$

$t^{-1}\pi/2>arg(z'')-arg(z)> t^{-1}3\pi/2; t<0$

I tried using Taylor series of $tan^{-1}(y''/x'')$ since I needed the argument of $z''$ and at this point I ran out of ideas. I'd like to know if it has or not a solution, and if so a way to find it.